# Electric field along coaxial cylinders

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

Imagine two coaxial cylinders, one that is a volume with radius $Ra$ (and charge per unit lenght $-\lambda$) and another one that is just a surface with radius $Rc$ (and charge per unit lenght $+\lambda$), with $Rc > Ra$. What is the magnitude of the electric field everywhere in this distribution?

So the answer I have is this:
$$  E(r) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{, if $r < Ra$} \\
\frac{1}{2\pi \mathcal{E}_0}\frac{\lambda}{r}, & \text{, if $Ra<r<Rc$} \\
0, & \text{, if Rc < r}
\end{cases}
 $$

My questions regard all the three positions. Why is the Electric field zero in the $r<Ra$ and the $Rc<r$ regions? And in the middle region, shouldn't the electric field be the sum of the fields created by the two charges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be answered easily on the theorem of Gauss law..
In the three cases consider a imaginary cylinder at first radius

Notice that charge enclosed in first case is 0 second case is λ*l and third case is again 0

Thus E.2πr*l=charge enclosed/epsilon
Putting values give desired result

Comment: Yes, but why are the charges enclosed in the first and third cases zero?

Comment: Charges reside on the surface and in first case it encloses no charged surface

Comment: In third case final charge adds up to 0 due to induction